# Vue storing compoenents and rendering them later

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Vue and want to storing components in a ArrayList. Later I access that array list and attempt to render those components from the ArrayList. How would I go about doing this and is this a bad idea?

I just don't want to repeat myself and do this for example...

```html
<Example arg1="instance.data.arg1" arg2="instance.data.arg2" ...so on and so on />
```

because, lets say I add a new arg to instance, then everywhere in my code I have to go add arg3 now.

Comment: For anyone looking at this question for an answer, I think you can probably just create your own separate file and class to represent what you want and pass that as an arg. I just want to see if there are any other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this question for an answer, I think you can probably just create your own separate file and class to represent what you want and pass that as an arg. I just want to see if there are any other solutions.